# Python how to open an image URL from MySql, where the value has the directory

Tags: python, mysql

I am using Python and MySql.

This is my table and values inside the MySQL table called **img**

```
id    img_name                         url
1        A        C:/Users/Eduards/Desktop/work/test.jpg
2        B        C:/Users/Eduards/Desktop/work/test2.jpg
```

Here is my Python script

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

# SQL
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='signoff',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='test')
    sql_select_Query = "select url from img"
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    print(records[0])


except Error as e:
    print("Error reading data from MySQL table", e)

finally:
    if (connection.is_connected()):
        connection.close()
        cursor.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

on line where it scripted `print(records[0])` that is the file directory I am trying to open up.

Output of `print(records[0])` is `('C:/Users/Eduards/Desktop/work/test.jpg',)`

How can I simply open up that directory using this script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated python script to this, with help from Ofer Sadan:

```
sql_select_Query = "select url from img where id =%s"
id = (1,)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql_select_Query, id)
records = cursor.fetchone()
print()
for row in records:
    print(row)

#Open image
img = row
os.startfile(img)
```

Have used this https://pynative.com/python-mysql-select-query-to-fetch-data/ to help me out.

Replaced `fetchall` to `fetchdone` so it returns one value instead of all

Answer (score 0):

These are filepaths, not urls. Either way, if you want to open a directory on windows explorer from python, you can just use the `os` module:

```
import os
img = 'C:\\Path\\to\\some.jpg'
directory = os.path.dirname(img) # to get the parent folder
os.startfile(directory)
```

Comment: `img = records([0])
os.startfile(img)`
this is what I am trying to do, open the file directory from MySQL table value